# Is there a simple eclipse plugin that is free and let me fire soap requests and see soap responses in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, webservice-client

would like to know if there is any web service testing tool eclipse plugin. 
I looked at soap ui eclipse plugin , but its to big to get it installed in my environment.

Is there a simple eclipse plugin that is free and let me fire soap requests and see soap responses in Eclipse?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a built-in tool (the **Web Services Explorer**, part of the WTP?) allowing to test a web service and inspect the response. See [3.1 Using the Web Services Explorer to test a Web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/initial-contribution/IBM/evalGuides/WebServicesToolsEval.html#tour-wse).